# Find generic sub-lists within a list

Tags: python, regex, list, recursion

Just learning Python as my first coding language. Given a list with many possible sub-lists which have a variable number of elements, is there a way of using regex (or something similar) to identify which lists contain sub-lists with 1) the number of elements specified and 2) a given type of content in a certain order (including other sub-lists)? For example (in pseudocode):

```
list1 = [1, 4, 7, ["a", 5, "b"], 2, 4,7,"k",9]
list2 = [1, 4, 7, ["a", "h", "b"], 2]
list3 = [1, 4, 7, ["a", ["a", 6, "b"], "b"], 5, 3]

list4 = [1, 4, 7, ["a", "b"], 3, 4]
list5 = [1, 4, 7, ["a", 5, "b", 7], 3, 4]

if ["a", ., "b"] in listx: # where "." stands for anything, even sub-lists
     print("yes")
else:
     print("no")
```

list1, list2, and list3 should print "yes", but list4 and list5 should print "no".

As a bonus, is there a way to return 1) the number of times that the specified generic sub-list is found and 2) where? For example, have list3 return "There are 2 ["a", ., "b"] sub-lists, which are list3[3] and list3[3][1]"

I know I could convert the whole thing to a string and parse it, but this doesn't seem like a very elegant or efficient solution. Thank you!

Comment: My guess is that recursion would help a lot...is this homework?

Comment: No homework. Just a PhD student in another field trying to expand their skillset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that converting to string doesn't make any sense here, but regular expressions explicitly search strings so you're not looking for that either. You're looking for a recursive solution that tests for your rules, which are (essentially)

> somelist IS or CONTAINS a list that begins with the string "a", ends with the string "b", and has three or more elements.

Codify that into:

```
def flat_pass(lst):
    return len(lst) >= 3 and lst[0] == 'a' and lst[-1] == 'b'
```

Now you just have to recurse (to catch the "CONTAINS" part of the above rules)

```
def recurse_pass(lst):
    if len(lst) >= 3 and lst[0] == 'a' and lst[-1] == 'b':
        # base case
        return True
    # otherwise, flow continues...
    for el in lst:
        if isinstance(el, list):
            # recursive case
            if recurse_pass(el):
                return True
    return False
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! Unfortunately, I thought it would be fairly straightforward to modify the code you gave to be able to return the number of times the sub-list appears in the original list and where (the bonus in the original question), but so far I have not been able to come up with a solution that works. I was able to find a similar thread here with a possible solution (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13205875/add-an-item-into-a-list-recursively), but again, for some reason I am unable to make it work for my case.